# Cython: Speed up simple code

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to speed up the following code with Cython. Two arguments are imported from python:

**processing_times:** List with 500 lists of 20 integers each (500x20).

**sequence:** List with 500 integers.

```
cimport cython
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cpdef taillard_acceleration(sequence, processing_times, int job_inserted, int num_machines):

    # Static arrays - number of jobs limited to 500 jobs and 20 machines
    cdef int e[501][21]
    cdef int q[501][21]
    cdef int f[501][21]
    cdef int ms[501]

    # Variables
    cdef int sequence_length, best_makespan, best_position
    cdef int i, j, iq, jq, tmp

    # Initialize some values
    sequence_length = len(sequence)
    iq = sequence_length + 1


    for i in range(1, sequence_length + 2):
        if i < sequence_length + 1:
            e[i][0] = 0

            # Q index I
            iq = iq - 1
            q[iq][num_machines + 1] = 0

        f[i][0] = 0
        jq = num_machines + 1


        for j in range(1, num_machines + 1):
            if i == 1:
                e[0][j] = 0
                q[sequence_length + 1][num_machines + 1 - j] = 0
            if i < sequence_length + 1:
                # Q Index J
                jq = jq - 1

                if e[i][j - 1] > e[i - 1][j]:
                    e[i][j] = e[i][j - 1] + processing_times[sequence[i - 1]-1][j-1]
                else:
                    e[i][j] = e[i - 1][j] + processing_times[sequence[i - 1]-1][j-1]

                if q[iq][jq + 1] > q[iq + 1][jq]:
                    q[iq][jq] = q[iq][jq + 1] + processing_times[sequence[iq - 1]-1][jq-1]
                else:
                    q[iq][jq] = q[iq + 1][jq] + processing_times[sequence[iq - 1]-1][jq-1]

            # f(ij) = max {f(i, j-1), e(i-1, j)}
            if f[i][j - 1] > e[i - 1][j]:
                f[i][j] = f[i][j - 1] + processing_times[job_inserted-1][j-1]
            else:
                f[i][j] = e[i - 1][j] + processing_times[job_inserted-1][j-1]


    # Makespam - job k in position i
    best_makespan = 0
    best_position = 0
    for i in range(1, sequence_length + 2):
        ms[i] = 0
        for j in range(1, num_machines + 1):
            tmp = f[i][j] + q[i][j]
            if tmp > ms[i]:
                ms[i] = tmp
        # Check best insertion position
        if ms[i] < best_makespan or best_makespan == 0:
            best_makespan = ms[i]
            best_position = i


    return best_position, best_makespan
```

I was able to speed up the process 4x times over the original python code:

```
Just Python: 0.04114614830813535
With Cython: 0.00937230621550278
Cython is 4.390183948543561 times faster
```

How can i get a better speed improvement in this code?

I have already tryed to convert sequence and processing_times to numpy arrays outside and then use Memory views, but I got no improvement in that.

```
cpdef taillard_acceleration(sequence_np, processing_times_np, int job_inserted, int num_machines):

    # memory view
    cdef int [:, :] processing_times = processing_times_np
    cdef int [:] sequence = sequence_np
```

Also should I use malloc for q,e,f,ms arrays? First time using Cython, so i dont know if im doing this right. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question might be better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This type of question is on-topic here (although it's also on-topic at codereview). For Cython questions people usually have a better chance of getting a decent answer here than on codereview so we usually don't recommend moving it.

Comment: alias `f[i]` so you don't have to access the element in the inner loop.

Comment: @DavidW: I disagree with both points. "If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following area...
**Performance** ... then you are in the right place!" (CodeReview/on-topic). Also, there is a pretty good chance some of SO users know all about taxes and would be able to write a decent answer to tax questions. That does not make it a good place to ask.

Comment: @usr2564301 I agree it is on topic at codereview. I don't see anything in the SO help to say it isn't on topic here though (i.e. it is "a specific programming problem"). The only reason I don't really recommend moving it is that there's a pretty low volume of Cython questions at code review, so few of the Cython experts check it regularly - that's kind of a self-perpetuating problem though...

Answer (score 1):

Most of it looks like it's properly typed and so you're unlikely to get huge improvements. The main thing that isn't typed are `sequence` and `processing_times`. You should make these memoryviews:

```
def taillard_acceleration(int[:] sequence, int[:,:] processing_times, int job_inserted, int num_machines):
```

I know you already tried this, however you should also change their indexing to be of the form `processing_times[i,j]` (rather than `processing_times[i][j]`). What you're doing creates an 1D memoryview as a temporary object which is likely to be a little slower.

---

For the `q`, `e`, `f`, and `ms` arrays: what you're doing now is absolutely fine if you're happy recompiling to change the sizes. If you think you might want to change the sizes at runtime then you should allocate them at runtime. You could use `malloc` but I'd use:

```
cdef int[:,::1] e = np.zeros((501,21))
```

(the `[:,::1]` tells Cython that the array is 2D and contiguous). Using numpy like this would be *very slightly* slower than `malloc`, but it's also a lot easier and a lot less likely for you to get it wrong. If you do this then change their indexing to `e[i,j]` as described above.

(It looks like they really should be of the size `sequency_length` by `num_machines` so a runtime size might be a good idea)

Comment: The problem with the memory view was their indexing. Just changing to processing_times[i,j] resulted in almost 3x speed-up. Cython is 11 times faster than the original code in Python now. Thanks!